# What's the proper spring cloud release working with current spring boot 2.0.0M3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-webflux

I would like to use spring boot 2.0.0M3(which includes Spring 5 RC3) for my new project. I'm wondering which release of spring cloud I should use to have compatible with spring 5.

I did not find any resource talking about it. Should I use latest Dalston SR2 or Finchley snapshot to having spring cloud capability?

Comment: I doubt there already is a version supporting that version. Also be aware that Spring Boot 2 and Spring aren't final yet .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generated my new project via [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io).

The **Finchley.M1** of spring cloud works fine with spring boot 2.0.0.M3.